# Who were the first statisticians in the USA, and in the world, in two different cases...?

Tags: history

Who were the first statisticians in the USA, and in the world, in two different cases, to be awarded a statistics PhD degree and what were the corresponding award years?

Note: The discipline of statistics was new, compared to other subjects.

Comment: I'm not sure this has a clear cut answer, as the pioneering statisticians were all  mathematicians in name? rather than statistician specifically

Comment: I don't know if he was first in the world ( he was british ) but Fisher was a giant and was early. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher. I would check out who his advisor was , assuming he had one.

Comment: @Xiaomi I think the main point in my question here is try to ask the time when the first statistics phd is offered, not mathematics since I consider the first statistics PHD program to be the first uniformly high quality, mass productive "statistician manufacturing machine" in variety of different stat field